How would I connect this device to 2 separate networks so that it's accessible from the one, but also has internet from the other?
I think the diagram I created says it all. I need to install and configure the device at the bottom (the data manager). It is connected to 4 solar inverters.
I have 2 ethernet cables available. One is from the central Energy Management System that needs to be able to talk to the data manager. The other is from the internet router.
I need the data manager to be able to:

Be accessed by the EMS system.
The data manager to be connected to the internet so it an talk to a cloud service.

How could I achieve this with the situation in the diagram? I only have access to the data manager and the 2 provided ethernet cables.


Routers route between networks. However, your question is off topic here, see [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su].

You can do this by setting the default gateway to be the 192.168.2.x and making sure the 192.168.2.x range has the better metric in the routing table. And if your switching environment supports vlans you can even do this with a single cable.

For the love of god... contract someone with knowledge of securing Industrial IT systems. Do not expose such systems to the internet. They tend to - at best - have poort security. At worst, they have no security by 1980-standards...
